# What's difference between "backing pixel data" and bitmap object?

Tags: android, bitmap

I am reading the http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/manage-memory.html again.

I can't understand the below line clearly:

> On Android 2.3.3 (API level 10) and lower, the backing pixel data for a bitmap is stored in native memory. It is separate from the bitmap itself, which is stored in the Dalvik heap.

What's the difference between **backing pixel data** and **bitmap object**?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The **bitmap object** is an instance of the [Bitmap class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html).  While I don't have the source of the Bitmap class in front of me, I would assume it has the following private member variables: width, height, color depth, "has alpha channel", dpi, etc...  That is, all the metadata about the image itself that a program or renderer might need to know about the image.

The **backing pixel data** is the actual uncompressed (A)RGB bytes decoded from the source file that used to create the instance of this bitmap object.  So if the bitmap represents a 640x480 24bit image loaded from a JPEG, there's likely a backing array of 640x480x3 bytes allocated somewhere and is a private member of the Bitmap class. Methods like getPixel and setPixel work directly on the array.

As for the Dalvik vs. Native memory thing.  The thing to keep in mind is that Bitmap objects use a lot of memory.  If your code references too many Bitmap objects, it could run out of memory.

The complete quote from that web link you list:

> To set the stage for this lesson, here is how Android's management of bitmap memory has evolved:
>   On Android Android 2.2 (API level 8) and lower, when garbage
>   collection occurs, your app's threads get stopped. This causes a lag
>   that can degrade performance. Android 2.3 adds concurrent garbage
>   collection, which means that the memory is reclaimed soon after a
>   bitmap is no longer referenced.
>
> On Android 2.3.3 (API level 10) and
>   lower, the backing pixel data for a bitmap is stored in native memory.
>   It is separate from the bitmap itself, which is stored in the Dalvik
>   heap. The pixel data in native memory is not released in a predictable
>   manner, potentially causing an application to briefly exceed its
>   memory limits and crash. As of Android 3.0 (API level 11), the pixel
>   data is stored on the Dalvik heap along with the associated bitmap.

The quote is trying to say is this.  Bitmaps use a lot of memory since they are usually backed by a large memory allocation to hold the ARGB bytes. On today's Android OS, the ARGB bytes associated with the Bitmap get garbage collected along with the Bitmap object itself when it's no longer referenced. So as long as you don't have a reference leak with your instances of the Bitmap class, the garbage collector will do the right thing and prevent you from running out of memory - as any programmer would likely want and expect.

On earlier versions of Android, the ARGB bytes were managed by a different runtime and garbage collector separate from the app's own Java/Dalvik runtime. So on the older Android models, just because the Bitmap object itself was cleaned up by garbage collection, the image bytes might be cleaned up much later.  So if you were to continuously load and release many Bitmaps very quickly, you might run out of memory even if you did everything correct to ensure the Bitmap objects managed by your Java code were no longer referenced.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation really helpfull